# Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced

Tags: javascript, html, compiler-errors

I am trying to load a module from the init2.js file and I keep getting an error Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //lading the javascript module
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "init2.js";
        script.type = "module";
        document.head.append(script);

        //redirecting to error page if module/script fails to load
        script.onerror = function() {
            //window.location.href = "error.html";
        }

        //onsubmit of form function
        function localStor() {
            var inputFName = document.getElementById("fname");
            var inputLName = document.getElementById("lname");
            var inputEmail = document.getElementById("email");

            window.localStorage.setItem("first name", inputFName.value);
            window.localStorage.setItem("last name", inputLName.value);
            window.localStorage.setItem("email", inputEmail.value);
        }
    </script>
    <!--<script src="init.js" type="module"></script>-->
    <title>Cupcake & Ice Cream Creator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Cupcake & Ice Cream Creator</h1>
    <div id="selects">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="choices">
    </div>
    <div id="selects2">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="choices2">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="img">
    </div>
    <h2>Contact Information</h2>
    <form name="contact" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" id="fname" required><br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" id="lname" required><br>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" required><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="localStor()"><br>
    </form>
    <br>
    <a href="index.html"><button>Start Over</button></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when I providing/referring the wrong **style.css** file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

Please check once your **css** and **script** file that your reference is correct or not. If you will give/provide a wrong reference then will see this error.